# Independent random variables defined over same probability space with same distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Is it possible that two real random variables $X_1,X_2$ are defined in the same probability space $(Ω,F,P)$ and have the same distribution and be independent ?

Comment: please provide reasoning for downvoting .

Comment: Why are you duplicating existing questions/answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I throw a penny and a dime.  $X_1$ is the event that the penny is $H$, $X_2$ is the event that the dime is $H$.

Comment: Those are discrete random variables.

Comment: Note: events are not random variables

Comment: @Furrane.  Did the OP specify otherwise?  Counting measure is a good measure, where it applies.

Comment: @YujieZha  So, make my $X_i$ the indicator variables for those events.

Comment: @lulu My bad, I misread.

Comment: So the answer to my question is yes . So what are these people talking here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736253/let-x-y-have-the-same-distribution-on-common-prob-space-do-they-generate-same)

Comment: @liaguridio "These people" are exactly explaining what you have just been explained here.

Comment: @liaguridio  I don't see the contradiction.

Comment: If the random variables are independent their sigma algebras are independent .

Comment: @liaguridio "If the random variables are independent their sigma algebras are independent" Indeed, actually this is the **definition** of two random variables being independent. And?

Comment: I suggest:  work with my example (which, of course, is exactly the same example as the one provided by @Did in your link).  Compute the sigma algebras generated by my variables.  Convince yourself that all is consistent here.

Comment: so the intersection of their sigma fields contains all the events that happen almost surely and all the events that do not happen almost surely , so these two sigma algebras are not necessarily the same .

Comment: At this point, I think you are asking questions more relevant to your link than to this post.  In my  discrete example notions of "surely" and "almost surely" are not relevant.  I suggest you post your questions on that post rather than here.

Comment: I cannot post a comment to the question provided in the link because of reputation .

Comment: ...And your immediate decision, when faced to this (quite motivated) disposition, is to bend the rules of the site?

Comment: How am I bending the rules of the site ?

Comment: The question you have asked here has been answered (I believe).  If there is another question you want to ask, post it separately.